# Difference between せんしゅう and ぜんしゅう

Tags: word-choice

I was looking at [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21186/how-would-you-talk-about-relative-time-in-the-past) and I discovered the word ぜんしゅう (last week).  I am familiar with せんしゅう, and I was wondering if there is any difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「[先週]{せんしゅう}」 can only mean one thing -- "last week", the week before this week.  Your stand point is right this moment -- the present.

「[前週]{ぜんしゅう}」 has two meanings:

1) same as 先週.

2) the preceding week of a particular week in the past that one is talking about.  Your stand point is in the past, not the present moment.  It can be a few weeks ago, many months or even years ago.

You will always be able to tell from the context which meaning 前週 is being used for.