# What is the difference between 次の週 and 来週?

Tags: words

I came across the following sentence:

その次の週は空いてますか。

1. Why would they say 次の週 instead of 来週?
2. Why would they say その before 次の週? Would この also work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why would they say 次の週 instead of 来週?**

Because like the phrase `next week` in English, `来週` is generally assumed to be relative to the time when it is uttered.

> 来週は空いていますか。
>
> Are (you) free next week?

Is a question about whether someone is free in the next week after whenever it was asked. `来週` is not really used to talk about relative time in reference to anything other than the present. [次の週 can do that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21190/7705), though.

> その次の週は空いてますか。
>
> Are (you) free the following week (after some particular week)?

**Why would they say その before 次の週?**

To make it clear that this is the week after some relevant particular week. You might also think of this, meaning wise, like `それの次の週`, where `それ` is some week. As the post linked above says, this is optional, but frequently used.

**Would この also work?**

I would not expect to see `この` here in most cases, though I can conceive of situations where it could be appropriate, like if both parties were in front of a calendar and the speaker were pointing at weeks. I am not going to write an in-depth explanation of the difference between `その` and `この` here, as that doesn't seem to be what the question is about.